# RPC from Windows Client to Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, winapi, rpc, msrpc

I need to rpc from a windows 10 client to a linux (RHEL 7) server. I am very new to rpc (must be DCE RPC), so If you have a working example (hello world maybe?) that would be very helpful. I have seen this post: [RPC from Windows to linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087092/rpc-from-windows-to-linux) which says to use Samba, however I tried, and to no avail, did not come up with anything. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!